# How to make syncdb work automatically in Django?

Tags: python, django

When I have a view that helps in uploading of a file , I want it to be stored in the database , which is only possible if I run syncdb . But , till now I know how to run python manage.py syncdb at the python command line . How do I make it run automatically when I upload some data ?

Comment: please explain how it is working, because you can upload a file int the db without syncdb, so imho you should definitely not call syncdb all the time you upload a file

Comment: Uploading a file has nothing whatsoever to do with syncdb.

Comment: "I want it to be stored in the database , which is only possible if I run syncdb" - I'm not sure but something about that sentence triggers a little alarm bell in my head. Describe in a bit more detail what you want to achieve. The 'syncdb' bit might be a red-herring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little bit hacky way:

```
import sys
sys.argv.append('syncdb')

from django.core.management import execute_manager
import settings # Your project's settings. Assumed to be in the same directory. 

execute_manager(settings)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always call

```
os.system('python /path/manage.py syncdb')
```

This should run your syncdb process, however, I think there are better ways to solve this without using syncdb at all.

Oh, and you will need to use flag that going to answer y to all questions.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `syncdb` on every file upload is wrong per se, but answering your question. To call `syncdb` from inside code:

```
from django.core.management.commands.syncdb import Command as SyncDbCommand
SyncDbCommand().handle_noargs()
```

Comment: This gives `Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now` for me, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Django has a official way of [Running management commands from your code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/django-admin/#running-management-commands-from-your-code)